# How to select a nested json value for each host in my inventory and set_fact for reuse later

Tags: json, ansible

I am fairly new to Ansible and using the vmware_guest_disk_info module to produce the following json:

```
{
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "result_item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "guest_disk_info": {
                "0": {
                    "capacity_in_bytes": 103079215104,
                    "capacity_in_kb": 100663296,
                    "controller_bus_number": 0,
                    "controller_key": 1000,
                    "controller_type": "lsilogicsas",
                    "key": 2000,
                    "label": "Hard disk 1",
                    "summary": "100,663,296 KB",
                    "unit_number": 0
                },
                "1": {
                    "capacity_in_bytes": 8589934592,
                    "capacity_in_kb": 8388608,
                    "controller_bus_number": 0,
                    "controller_key": 1000,
                    "controller_type": "lsilogicsas",
                    "key": 2001,
                    "label": "Hard disk 2",
                    "summary": "8,388,608 KB",
                    "unit_number": 1
                }
            },
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "name": "server1",
                }
            },
            "result_item": {
                "vmname": "server1"
            }
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "result_item",
           "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "guest_disk_info": {
                "0": {
                    "capacity_in_bytes": 103079215104,
                    "capacity_in_kb": 100663296,
                    "controller_bus_number": 0,
                    "controller_key": 1000,
                    "controller_type": "lsilogicsas",
                    "key": 2000,
                    "label": "Hard disk 1",
                    "summary": "100,663,296 KB",
                    "unit_number": 0
                }
            },
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "name": "server2",
                }
            },
            "result_item": {
                "vmname": "server2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I need to be able to extract the unit_number from each host and then reference each hosts own unit_number(s) later in another task(there can be multiple unit numbers per host).  It seems everything I tried just overwrites the previous value and I only end up with the last value of the last host.

I have tried:

```
set_fact:
  facts: "{{ diskOutput.results.guest_disk_info.values()|map(attribute='unitNumber'} | list }}"
```

But I only get the last hosts data.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Assign the next consecutive unused unit_number to the new disk.**"*

A: Create a dictionary of the servers and their units, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        srv_units: "{{ dict(_servers|zip(_units)) }}"
      vars:
        _servers: "{{ diskOutput.results|
                      json_query('[].result_item.vmname') }}"
        _units: "{{ diskOutput.results|
                    json_query('[].guest_disk_info.*.unit_number') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  srv_units:
    server1:
    - 0
    - 1
    server2:
    - 0
```

Then iterate this dictionary and find the next units, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} next unit: {{ item.value|max + 1 }}"
      loop: "{{ srv_units|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'server1 next unit: 2'
  msg: 'server2 next unit: 1'
```

Comment: That works to get a list of values but how do you reference it later to know that server1 unit_number values are 0,1 and server2 unit_number is 0.  I'm trying to add a disk to multiple VMs and want to assign the next consecutive unused unit_number to the new disk.  So for server1, it will be unit_number=2 and for server2, it will be unit_number=1.  Thanks for your response.  It was very helpful.

Comment: It's clear now. I've updated the answer. You're welcome. Make sure next time you put down [mre]. An expected result is very helpful, especially when enumerated.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I got the debug to work as shown.  But how do you then reference only server1's or server 2's "next unit" in later tasks?